# Gamma correction of Sentinel-2 imagery using Leaflet

Tags: leaflet, geotiff-tiff, cloud-optimized-geotiff

Image Stripes after applying a Gamma correction after normalization with  this [Sentinel2, 4 Band DN](https://d29cp2gnktw6by.cloudfront.net/data/S2_LEVEL_2A/20240101T102431/S2_L2A_SR_20240101T102431_20240101T102428_10M_run20240102.tif)  using Leaflet ([Complete Code](https://gist.github.com/davidoesch/645ff696b9101a2c343caac5e369f3ac)) with this code:

```
  <body>
<div id="map"></div>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.0.3/dist/leaflet.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/proj4js/2.6.0/proj4.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/georaster"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/georaster-layer-for-leaflet"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/proj4leaflet/1.0.2/proj4leaflet.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet-proj4leaflet"></script> <!-- Import Proj4Leaflet extension -->

<script>
  // Define custom CRS for EPSG 2056
  var crs2056 = new L.Proj.CRS('EPSG:2056',"+proj=somerc +lat_0=46.95240555555556 +lon_0=7.439583333333333 +k_0=1 +x_0=2600000 +y_0=1200000 +ellps=bessel +towgs84=674.374,15.056,405.346,0,0,0,0 +units=m +no_defs",  {    resolutions: [1024, 512, 256, 128, 64, 32, 16, 8, 4, 2, 1, 0.5, 0.25, 0.125, 0.0625],
origin: [2485071.58, 1299941.79],  } );

  // Initialize Leaflet map with custom CRS
  var map = L.map('map', {
    crs: crs2056
  }).setView([46, 8], 1);
  
var map4 = new L.tileLayer.wms("https://wms0.geo.admin.ch/", {
layers: 'ch.vbs.milairspacechart',
format: 'image/png',
transparent: true,
crs: crs2056
}).addTo(map);

  // Add OpenStreetMap basemap
  //L.tileLayer('http://{s}.tile.osm.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
  //    attribution: '&copy; <a href="http://osm.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
  //}).addTo(map);

  const url_to_geotiff_file = new URLSearchParams(location.search).get("url");
  console.log("url_to_geotiff_file:", url_to_geotiff_file);

  if (!url_to_geotiff_file) {
    setTimeout(function() {
      // If no URL is provided, redirect to a sample GeoTIFF
      const parser = new URL(window.location);
      parser.searchParams.set("url", "https://d29cp2gnktw6by.cloudfront.net/data/S2_LEVEL_2A/20240101T102431/S2_L2A_SR_20240101T102431_20240101T102428_10M_run20240102.tif");
      window.location = parser.href;
    }, 2 * 1000);
  } else {
    console.log("url_to_geotiff_file:", url_to_geotiff_file);
    // Parse the GeoTIFF data
    parseGeoraster(url_to_geotiff_file).then(function (georaster) {
      console.log("georaster:", georaster);

      const vizParamsWATER = {
        bands: ['B4', 'B3', 'B2'],
        min: 400,
        max: 3200,
        gamma: [1.7, 1.7, 1.4]
      };

      const layer = new GeoRasterLayer({
        attribution: "'Contains modified Copernicus Sentinel data [Year]' for Sentinel data",
        debugLevel: 0,
        georaster,
        resolution: 512,
        resampleMethod: "nearest",
        pixelValuesToColorFn: values => {
          // Check if any of the bands have a value of 9999 or 0
          if (values.some(value => value === 9999 || value === 0)) {
            // If any band has a value of 9999 or 0, return transparent color
            return 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)'; // Transparent color
          } else {
            // Apply min-max normalization to each band
            const r = (values[0] - vizParamsWATER.min) / (vizParamsWATER.max - vizParamsWATER.min);
            const g = (values[1] - vizParamsWATER.min) / (vizParamsWATER.max - vizParamsWATER.min);
            const b = (values[2] - vizParamsWATER.min) / (vizParamsWATER.max - vizParamsWATER.min);

            // Apply gamma correction to each band
            const gammaR = Math.pow(r, 1 / vizParamsWATER.gamma[0]);
            const gammaG = Math.pow(g, 1 / vizParamsWATER.gamma[1]);
            const gammaB = Math.pow(b, 1 / vizParamsWATER.gamma[2]);

            // Return RGB color
            return `rgba(${gammaR * 255},${gammaG * 255},${gammaB * 255})`;
          }
        }
      });

      layer.addTo(map);
      map.fitBounds(layer.getBounds());
    });
  }
</script>
```

I get the following result

A) Artefacts, Lines in the image, (I do get the same artefacts if I use [EPSG 3857 code](https://gist.github.com/davidoesch/180b708760f656578f2343a37a17bf65))

[image: Artefacts]

If I apply only min max normalization like this

```
                // Apply min-max normalization to each band
            const r = Math.round((values[0] - vizParamsWATER.min) / (vizParamsWATER.max - vizParamsWATER.min)*255) ;
            const g = Math.round((values[1] - vizParamsWATER.min) / (vizParamsWATER.max - vizParamsWATER.min)*255) ;
            const b = Math.round((values[2] - vizParamsWATER.min) / (vizParamsWATER.max - vizParamsWATER.min)*255) ;
            return `rgba(${r},${g},${b})`;
```

then there are no stripes. Seems like  the Gamma Correction is the issue:

```
// Apply gamma correction to each band
            const gammaR = Math.pow(r, 1 / vizParamsWATER.gamma[0]);
            const gammaG = Math.pow(g, 1 / vizParamsWATER.gamma[1]);
            const gammaB = Math.pow(b, 1 / vizParamsWATER.gamma[2]);
```

expected result:
-> Applied gamma correction with no stripes in the imagery

Comment: Problem is on your [r, g, b] conversion formulas. Sometimes they return negative value, so computed gamma value has `NaN` value then. Just checking for negative value and setting it to 0 works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved. I used this approach (formulas come from here https://custom-scripts.sentinel-hub.com/custom-scripts/sentinel-2/l2a_optimized/):

```
parseGeoraster(url_to_geotiff_file).then(function (georaster) {
        console.log("georaster:", georaster);
        // based on https://custom-scripts.sentinel-hub.com/custom-scripts/sentinel-2/l2a_optimized/    
        const maxR = 3.0; // max reflectance
        const midR = 0.13;
        const sat = 1.2;
        const gamma = 1.8;
        const gOff = 0.01;
        const gOffPow = Math.pow(gOff, gamma);
        const gOffRange = Math.pow(1 + gOff, gamma) - gOffPow;

        function sAdj(a) {
            return adjGamma(adj(a, midR, 1, maxR));
        }

        function adjGamma(b) {
            return (Math.pow((b + gOff), gamma) - gOffPow) / gOffRange;
        }

        function satEnh(r, g, b) {
            const avgS = (r + g + b) / 3.0 * (1 - sat);
            return [clip(avgS + r * sat), clip(avgS + g * sat), clip(avgS + b * sat)];
        }

        function clip(s) {
            return s < 0 ? 0 : s > 1 ? 1 : s;
        }

        function adj(a, tx, ty, maxC) {
            var ar = clip(a / maxC, 0, 1);
            return ar * (ar * (tx / maxC + ty - 1) - ty) / (ar * (2 * tx / maxC - 1) - tx / maxC);
        }

        //const sRGB = (c) => c <= 0.0031308 ? (12.92 * c) : (1.055 * Math.pow(c, 0.41666666666) - 0.055);
        const layer = new GeoRasterLayer({
            attribution: "Contains modified Copernicus Sentinel data 2024",
            debugLevel: 0,
            georaster,
            resolution: 512,
            resampleMethod: "nearest",
            pixelValuesToColorFn: values => {
                // Check if any of the bands have a value of 9999 or 0
                if (values.some(value => value === 9999 || value === 0)) {
                    // If any band has a value of 9999 or 0, return transparent color
                    return 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)'; // Transparent color
                } else {
                    // Apply min-max normalization to each band
                    const r = (Math.round((sAdj(values[0]/10000))*255));
                    const g = (Math.round((sAdj(values[1]/10000))*255));
                    const b = (Math.round((sAdj(values[2]/10000))*255));

                    // Return RGB color
                    return `rgba(${r},${g},${b},1)`;
                }
            }
        });

        layer.addTo(map);
        map.fitBounds(layer.getBounds());
    });
```

This is how it looks then:

[image]

Comment: third line in code snippet above  // based on https://custom-scripts.sentinel-hub.com/custom-scripts/sentinel-2/l2a_optimized/